# discord currency bot keeps saying get_bank_data() is undefined

Tags: python, discord.py

My discord currency bot keeps saying get_bank_data is undefined when i already did

```
async def get_bank_data():
        with open("kromerbank.json", "r") as f:
                users = json.load(f)
```

someone help
some of my code for the bot is below. I think most of the code works but the only error i get is get_bank_data is undefined so idk what I did wrong

```html
   
   client.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()


    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
    bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]


    em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance",color = discord.Color.red())
    em.add_field(name = "wallet balance",value = wallet_amt)
    em.add_field(name = "bank balance",value = bank_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)


@client.command()
async def beg(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    users = await get_bank_data()
    user = ctx.author
    earnings = random.randrange(101)


    await ctx.send("Someone gave you {earnings} kromer!")



    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings

    with open("kromerbank.json", "r") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)


async def open_account(user):
    
    users = await get_bank_data()
    
    if str(user.id) in users: 
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0


    with open("kromerbank.json", "r") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
    return True





    async def get_bank_data():
        with open("kromerbank.json", "r") as f:
            users = json.load(f)

        return users
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put `@client.command()` before the async declaration:

```
@client.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()


    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
    bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"]


    em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance",color = discord.Color.red())
    em.add_field(name = "wallet balance",value = wallet_amt)
    em.add_field(name = "bank balance",value = bank_amt)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)


@client.command()
async def beg(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)

    users = await get_bank_data()
    user = ctx.author
    earnings = random.randrange(101)


    await ctx.send("Someone gave you {earnings} kromer!")



    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings

    with open("kromerbank.json", "r") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)

@client.command()
async def open_account(user):
    
    users = await get_bank_data()
    
    if str(user.id) in users: 
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0


    with open("kromerbank.json", "r") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
    return True




@client.command()
async def get_bank_data():
    with open("kromerbank.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    return users
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you put the async in your `get_bank_data()`, is this work for you?

```
async def open_account(user):
    
    users = get_bank_data()
    
    if str(user.id) in users: 
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)] = {}
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0


    with open("kromerbank.json", "r") as f:
        json.dump(users,f)
    return True


def get_bank_data():
    with open("kromerbank.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    return users
```